# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException on googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true) Android Studio

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

So i am doing a project that i only need to get the location, i don't need to show the map or anything like that. I created the `GoogleMap mGoogleMap;` in the beginning of the class. When asking for the permission of location and course to the user i have this code:

```
   public class Distance extends Activity implements Runnable {
    //...
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    //...
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                        new MyLocationListener()
                );
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
            }
//...
```

The first time i ran the application it worked but the other times got this error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference.

That error is in the line that have: `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

I know that i need to initialize the googleMap object because it is blank but i don't know how. Help?

Comment: You have to initialize `GoogleMap mGoogleMap;` somehow before you access the object by `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`...

Comment: and how is "somehow"?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673084/how-to-set-location-on-start-google-maps-api-v2)...

Comment: Hopefully, you are not testing on an emulator. Make sure you have latest google play services on a physical android device and test it.

Comment: yes, i am testing it in my smartphone with android 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init the map this way:

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```